# Is there a way to know all ionic classes?

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've seen some classes you can use in a div or other html elements like `<div class="spacer">`
but i couldnt find a documentation about all the classes you can use with ionic.

Comment: Probably all you'll ever need to know is right in the documentation of the Ionic project http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/

Comment: Depending of your text editor, you can install plugins that do it, for example, the sublime text has "Ionic Framework Extended Autocomplete" and so on.